# FireFox not running code in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, setinterval

This is driving me a bit mad. I've got `setInterval` working fine for Chrome, IE and Safari, but FireFox is letting me down big time. With the code below, it's not setting the heights of the `<li>`'s I'm targeting - can you see why not?

```
    // For fullscreen overlay navigation
    var uid = '#my-ul-id'
            function osuFixLiHeights(targetUl) {    
                var t       = $(targetUl);
                var ch      = $(t).height();
                var lih     = ch / 2;
                $(t).find('li').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).removeAttr(); // clear heights first as it seems this is needed to re-add the heights
                    setInterval(function () {
                        $(this).height(lih); // delay adding heights
                    },100);
                });
            }
     osuFixLiHeights(uid);
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help so far, much appreciated. Updated code below - as mentioned in one of my comments, this is all working great for setting the initial heights of the `<li>`'s, the only outstanding issue I have is that when resizing the browser window from a smaller size to a larger size, the heights of the `<li>`'s are being set correctly, however, making the browser window smaller doesn't change the `<li>` heights.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var didResize = (function(){
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

function osuFixLiHeights(targetUl) {    
        var ch      = $(targetUl).height();
        var lih     = ch / 2;
        $(targetUl).find('li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).removeAttr(); // clear heights first
            var targetLi = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(targetLi).height(lih); // delay adding heights 
            }, 100);
        });
    }

$(window).resize(function() {
        didResize(function() {
            osuFixLiHeights('#menu-overlay-nav');
        }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure this works on chrome, IE, Safari??? Because it shouldn't regarding context of `this` inside interval callback, it should be e.g: `setInterval(function () {
                        $(this).height(lih); // delay adding heights
                    }.bind(this),100);`

Comment: Well, it is working in my browser, although I can see your point why it shouldn't....

Comment: Your observation regarding code working on other browsers is wrong for sure or maybe browser cache issue

Comment: Just reporting on what I'm seeing, not saying it should be working. Let me explain what I'm trying to do as I may have misunderstood how to use setInterval. I'm triggering this function when the window resizes so the <li> heights are always 50% high. My understanding is that setInterval is used to delay a part of a function from occurring for a set amount of time (in this case waiting until the styles / heights have been stripped from the <li>'s so the new heights can be applied). With your code above, it looks like the code inside setInterval is run every 100ms, is that to be expected?

Comment: Ya, this is expected behaviour. As i understand it, what you want is to use a timeout. Replace `setInterval(...)` with `setTimeout(...)`. If you want to animate it instead, consider to use `animate()` with `delay()` method

Comment: That's all very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem lies in the body of the `setInterval` function.
Try to assign `this` to a variable:

```
$(t).find('li').each(function(i) {
  $(this).removeAttr(); // clear heights first as it seems this is needed to re-add the heights
  var self = this; // Capture the current 'this' value
  setInterval(function () {
    // Here 'this' is not the same 'this' as before
    $(self).height(lih); // delay adding heights
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this fixed the issue of setting the initial heights of the <li>'s in FireFox, now the only thing I'm trying to figure out is why resizing the window adjusts the heights of the <li>'s correctly when going from a smaller sized window to a bigger one but not vice versa. (I'll update the code above in a moment so the latest is there)